# Excel worksheet object does not equal the same worksheet object

Tags: c#, excel, vba

First part of code:

```
activeWorksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
var allWorksheets = new List<Worksheet>();
```

This is what I am testing:

```
allWorksheets.Add(activeWorksheet);
Debug.WriteLine(activeWorksheet.Name); //prints Sheet1
Debug.WriteLine(allWorksheets[0].Name); //prints Sheet1
Debug.WriteLine(allWorksheets[0] == activeWorksheet); //prints true
```

When I run this in background as a task, it does not work however. It returns `false` when I perform that last comparison, even though it prints Sheet1 and Sheet1.

```
new Task(() =>
{
    allWorksheets.Add(activeWorksheet);
    Debug.WriteLine(activeWorksheet.Name); //prints Sheet1
    Debug.WriteLine(allWorksheets[0].Name); //prints Sheet1
    Debug.WriteLine(allWorksheets[0] == activeWorksheet); //prints false
}
```

Is there some weird background behaviour with worksheets in Excel? I have resorted to comparing worksheet names temporarily, but shouldn't this be working?

Comment: Could you post more code? How/where  is the ```activeWorksheet``` declared and how is it set? The same question for ```allWorksheets```.

Comment: I can only guess... here the compiler closes over the variables which are declared outside of the lambda expression and the compiler probably must create a new class with all the variables needed to execute the code. You will have to decompile and watch what was generated so you can find out why the last comparison returns false.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I think that `Worksheet` didn't implement the Equals method right. So if it is the same instance it is equal, but if a new instance of the same Worksheet is created the Equals method returns false.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I created a wrapper object for `Interop.Excel.Worksheet` and implemented this equals method:

```
 Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean

    Dim other = TryCast(obj, Worksheet)
    If other Is Nothing Then Return False
    Return ParentsAreEqual(other) AndAlso _worksheet.Name.Equals(other._worksheet.Name) 

End Function

Private Function ParentsAreEqual(other As Worksheet) As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean
    Try
        result = _worksheet.Parent.Equals(other._worksheet.Parent)
    Catch ex As Exception
        result = False
    End Try
    Return result

End Function

Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer

    Try
        Return _worksheet.Parent.GetHashCode() Xor _worksheet.Name.GetHashCode
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return 42
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: I ended up just checking worksheet name, since Excel can't have duplicate sheet names and that was enough for my case, but this is pretty sweet too.

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize your object comparison by also checking the workbook names. Else you might get a wrong result if two open workbooks have identical sheet names. A simple function for that below:

```
Function Worksheet_is_worksheet(sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet) As Boolean
   'Function to circumvent (known but unresolved) issues with object comparison for 
    'worksheets

    Worksheet_is_worksheet = (sh.Name = sh2.Name) And _
        (sh.Parent.Name =  sh2.Parent.Name)

End Function
```